# Show and hide content on scroll with vh or %?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I am building some test split screen layouts and would like to show / hide content based on scroll position. As I have built layouts in VH set scroll position in VH too? (although im switching text I would like to learn how to show and hide by class/id so I can switch other content in the future.

[Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/thinkvisual/pen/JjKLjQv)

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y < 0) {
        $(".test1").hide();
    } else {
        $(".test1").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
var element =$("#it");
var element1 =$("#it1");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100) {
      element.hide();
      element1.show();
    } else {
      element.show();
      element1.hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</head>
<body style="height :2000px;">
<div id="it" style="background-color:red;height :1000px;">TEST</div>
<div id="it" style="background-color:yellow;height :1000px;">TEST2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply - maybe i am missing something here, but I am finding it difficult to follow your example as I would like to avoid using pixels and use either % or VH to specificy scroll height - is this possible?